# How to get files from a shared folder protected username and password?

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share (windows server) and get the files?

Project compiled using android version: API Level 4.2

Answer (score 0):

From an `Xamarin.Android` project you can use `JCIFS` (http://jcifs.samba.org) to connect to a Windows share (password protected or not) and transfers files.

> CIFS is an Open Source client library that implements the CIFS/SMB networking protocol in 100% Java. CIFS is the standard file sharing protocol on the Microsoft Windows platform (e.g. Map Network Drive ...).

I did a binding wrapper for version `jcifs-1.3.18` 5 months ago for a project and you can grab the source from my github account if desired @ https://github.com/sushihangover/Xamarin.Android.jCIFS

Consult the documention at the library's site for usage:

- http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/